# How to keep browsers open after console is closed

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I am using selenium to do a bit of automation, but I would like to be able to keep the browser windows open even after the python console has been closed.

Here are my current settings for the webdriver:

```
capabilities = {
    'browserName': 'chrome',
    'version': '',
    'platform': 'ANY',
    'javascriptEnabled': True,
    'chromeOptions': {
        'useAutomationExtension': False,
        'forceDevToolsScreenshot': True,
        'detach': False,
        'args': ['--start-maximized', '--disable-infobars', '--log-level=3']
    }
}
driver = webdriver.Chrome(desired_capabilities=capabilities)
```

Does anyone know how I can achieve this? Thanks.

Comment: You can try something like adding `time.sleep(1000)` to the end of your script. It seems to allow me to keep the browser open after closing the console.

Comment: @Mihai Chelaru I can't, I'm doing stuff afterwards

Comment: Don't close the browser in your script.

Comment: @JeffC I'm not closing it

Comment: @JP How would you proceed with your `bit of automation` if _python console has been closed_, _WebDriver is closed/destroyed/dangling_? How would you control the orphaned _Browser_?

Comment: @DebanjanB I could put a time.sleep(X) where X is a large number after my code is done running but that's definitely not a good solution.

Comment: @JP Okay, Let me put it in a simple way, if you don't destroy the driver/browser within `tearDown()` before closing the _console_, the _driver/browser_ will turn stale. How do you plan to automate further?

Comment: @DebanjanB I think you're missing the point. I don't have a teardown function. I just want to keep the browsers open after the console is closed without using a ridiculous method like time.sleep(10000).

Comment: @JP What exactly do you mean by `console is closed`? Are you looking for a situation `driver` instance is _killed/dangling_ and your browser is still open?

Comment: @DebanjanB I literally mean I don't want the chrome browsers I've opened from within my python code to close when I exit the python console...

Comment: I don't use python but I do use C# and Java and the browser does not close unless you have code that specifically closes it. I would suggest you read up on how to debug in python and the IDE that you use. Put a breakpoint near the end of your code and step through it until the browser closes and see what line it's on. My guess is that you've got code in some framework somewhere that is closing the browser. Better yet... create a brand new script with no framework and launch the browser... does the browser close then?

Comment: @JeffC I created a script that is literally just the code in my post and it still closed the browser when I close the python console window.